# Как работать с функциональными клавишами

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите что угодно кроме функциональных клавиш");
if (Console.ReadLine() == "") break;

Console.WriteLine("Наш великолепный код пришел к своему не менее великолепному концу, начинаем заново");
```

вот тут я использую любую клавишу там буквы, цифры, и цикл начинает запускаться заново, но при нажатии функциональной клавиши оно сразу же закрывается, а мне надо чтобы при нажатии Escape програ спрашивала у меня закрыватть ли прогу или начинать цикл заново ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получилось, придется работать с консолью на более низком уровне перехватывая все нажатое.

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Выходим? (y/n): ");
            bool isExit = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'y';
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (isExit)
                break;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Ну нет, так нет.");
        }
        switch (keyInfo.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                Console.WriteLine();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                Console.Write("\b \b");
                break;
            default:
                Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
                break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Пока.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

```
привет мир
Выходим? (y/n): ы
Ну нет, так нет.
еще раз привет

Выходим? (y/n): y
Пока.
```

Можно даже вот так проверять

```cs
bool isExit = Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y;
```

Тогда даже когда русский включен, будет срабатывать.

Comment: Игнорировать выбранную пользователем локаль, наверное, неправильно. А то например в немецкой локали Y и Z поменялись местами, и юзер, который считает, что нажал Z, внезапно по нашему как бы нажал Y. Я бы смотрел только на `KeyChar` при проверке букв.

Comment: Особенно на русском: юзер печатает «н», имея в виду «нет», а у нас на консоли выводится Н, а программа реагирует как будто бы введено Y.

Comment: @VladD так в основном коде так и сделано

Comment: Ага, я вижу, я именно про последнюю часть ответа.